# I'm trying to position 5 headers side by side in css?

Tags: css, header

im trying to position the the list headers into my website side by side I already tried it with a float: left and margin-right: 32px; code but somehow its still not working im a newbie so im currently looking for answers in the internet. Could somebody provide me with code which position the headers side by side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
  <title>Fitness Website </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="appoooo.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: silver;">
  <section>
    <header>
      <a href="#" class="logo">Fitness</a>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a class="navigation" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation1" href="#">Online Business</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation2" href="#">Training</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation3" href="#">Hobbies Vlog</a></li>
        <li><a class="navigation4" href="#">Music</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

```
    height: 3px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation1  {
    float: left;
    width: 143px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation2  {
    float: left;
    width: 143px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}


.navigation3 {
    float: left;
    width: 143px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}


.navigation4  {
    float: left;
    width: 143px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    position: e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope this answered your question...

    https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_nowrap8
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>

<p>Try to resize the browser window.</p>
<p>A container with "flex-wrap: nowrap;" will never wrap its items.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Flexbox is not supported in Internet Explorer 10 or earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

```
</html>
```